# How do I monitor the performance of USB peripherals on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb, performance, dvd-burning, peripherals

I'm trying to monitor the performance of a USB DVD player/writer on Windows 10. I'm mainly interested in basic metrics like bytes read and written per second and latency. So far I'm not finding any good sources of information:

- The Perfmon USB counters do not have any instances so cannot be loaded
- Task Manager, Resource Monitor, and Process Explorer do not appear to show information about I/O to and from the DVD player

Are there other sources of information, or something I'm overlooking in the above sources?

Comment: According to [How to Identify USB Problems Using Performance Monitor - Windows 7 Tutorial](https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/how-to-identify-usb-problems-using-performance-monitor.html) it *should* be possible.